# How to verify the set of two vectors is a basis for the plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

Verify that B={(3,2,0),(0,2,3)} is a basis for the plane 2x[1]-3x[2]+2x[3]=0 in R3.
How to solve out this question?
And I have a question about this question. I thought dim(Rn)=n.So in this question the basis should have 3 vectors rather than two. So my question is how two vectors can be a basis in R3?
Thank you very much!

Comment: UW represent!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plane is 2 dimensional sitting inside of $\mathbb{R}^3$ so you only need two vectors for a basis for the plane.  To prove it is a basis you must show that it is a spanning set and it is linearly independent.

To show it is linearly independent suppose:

$$a(3,2,0) + b(0,2,3) = (0,0,0)$$

Then comparing the entries we see that $3a + 0b = 0$ so $a = 0$ and similarly $0a + 3b = 0$ so $b=0.$  Thus the set is linearly independent.  Since the vectors lie in the plan (easy check) and they are linearly independent, and since the plane is 2-dimensional it follows that they are a basis.

Comment: I got that! Thank you very much~